# SQL Query for range of dates

Tags: sql, date-range

Lets frame the question again---

```
  table1{date, bID, sName, fID}
    {11/05,B1,A1,P1}
    {12/05,B2,A2,P2}
    {13/05,B1,A3,P1}
    {15/05,B3,A4,P1}
    {16/05,B1,A5,P2}
    {19/05,B1,A6,P2}
```

This is the table and the data stored in the table is also specified...

Now the query that i want is that:-

Depending of fId (lets say, P1 is selected) it should display the data from table say from 11/05-17/05 (no date should be missed). The data retrieved is as follows:-

```
11/05,B1,A1
12/05,--,--
13/05,B1,A3
14/05,--,--
15/05,B3,A4
16/05,--,--
17/05,--,--
```

The data retrieved for a particular fID(say P1) is displayed.. Explaning the result...

1)    it displayed all data from 11/05-17/05 where fId is P1, if there is no date in the database, then also it should display null value for that date (i.e.14/05 date was not there in database, but still it displayed with a null value)..

2)    if fId for that particular date is not P1, then also it store a null value in result set..

Atlast the data is retrieved in result set,, and processed further..

So i want to write the query for this problemm,, is it possible..

Comment: You want 4 result sets or 1 ... my guess is 1 but in your Q you are stating 4

Comment: if result come from 1 result set, then that's too good,, but 4 will also do...

Comment: Be more precise. You want a query, that results in one row per date and bID? Is that correct? What else do you want to see? It would be best if you would write down the result you need for the given example data. Then it's important to know if date and bID are unique.

Comment: What's the server you're using?

Comment: well both the answers are correct.. but its the constraint that i can't mark correct to both answers. still u guys rock. thanx a lot..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No code here, just my thoughts.

You need to create a temporary table with dates ranging from your begin date to an end date, inclusive. And then `left join` `table1` with that temporary table on `date` column plus add `where fID = ?`.

Comment: This query will work,, i will frame this query.. but isn't there any shortest route to this,, as i will have to make this temp table everytime in my java source code and insert values, then query accordingly,, which would involve to much interaction with database...

Comment: Why would you want to create a temp table in Java code? I guess MySQL should have a capability of creating temp tables directly within SQL sent to server.

Comment: thats ok,, but everytime i need to modify the range of dates, then java code has to specify the range, n ask to delete data from temp table and then insert dates accordingly..

Comment: okeys... its fine.. i'vl try to incorporate this logic into my code.. thanks a lot sir.. thnx..

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer here mentions, a table with all the dates in it, and a `LEFT JOIN` is what you need.

Say you have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
{
    date    DATETIME
    bID     VARCHAR(10),
    sName   VARCHAR(10),
    fID     VARCHAR(10)
}
```

and then this date-table:

```
CREATE TABLE dates
(
    dt      DATETIME
)
```

and in this table you need to have all the dates for the range you want to display. Usually you populate it with a couple of years in both directions, but that's up to you.

*Note: For simplicity, I did not bother with primary keys in either table. You should of course make sure you have a primary key, and in the case of the `dates` table, it could be the `dt` column.*

Then to display the results you want:

```
SELECT
    dt,
    bID,
    sName
FROM
    dates
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON dt = date AND fld = 'P1'
ORDER BY
    dt
```

Note that the selection of only `P1` rows is done in the `JOIN` criteria. If you add a `WHERE` clause to do the same, you'll loose all dates that have no data.